# Search between 2 dates in webmatrix

Tags: razor, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I need to get results of a search between 2 dates in Webmatrix. I do not know how I need to have the search entered or what I am doing wrong. This is the code I have. I am not getting any errors but there is nothing but the column names displayed in the grid.

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Management";
var db = Database.Open("OMD");
var startdate = Request["startdate"];
var enddate = Request["enddate"];
var selectCommand ="SELECT * FROM Ordr Where Date BETWEEN '" + startdate + "' AND '" + enddate + "'";
var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand);
var grid = new WebGrid(source: selectedData, defaultSort: "Date", rowsPerPage:10);
}

   @grid.GetHtml(
    columns:grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Date", format:@<Text>@item.Date</Text>),
        grid.Column("Status", format:@<Text>@item.Status</Text>),
        grid.Column("OStore", format:@<Text>@item.OStore</Text>),
        grid.Column("CStore", format:@<Text>@item.CStore</Text>),
        grid.Column("Employee", format:@<Text>@item.Employee</Text>)
    )
    )
```

I am searching with format MM/DD/YYYY like it is in the table.

Comment: P.S. you really need to look up SQL Injection! http://xkcd.com/327

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to do it safely, using the Razor Database helper parameter conventions:

```
var db = Database.Open("OMD");
var startdate = Request["startdate"].AsDateTime();
var enddate = Request["enddate"].AsDateTime();
var selectCommand ="SELECT * FROM Ordr Where Date >= @0 AND Date <= @1";
var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, startdate, enddate);
```

Please read this for more information on working with data in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor): http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data

Comment: I used that code and again am generating no data but getting no errors. In the database it includes time. Do i need to include time in the search and if so how do I format that or is there a different problem? And I did read that article.  I see now how I need to format the query. Thank you.

Comment: What data type have you used for your Date column? DateTime? What happens if you run the query with actual dates in the Query editor in WebMatrix?

Comment: I thought I had it as datetime but it was on nvarchar but when I chnge it to datetime I get an error "An overflow occured while converting to datetime" it directs the error to this line "var selectedData = db.Query(selectCommand, startdate, enddate);"

Comment: I am using this query 
SELECT * FROM Ordr Where Date >= 8/1/2013 AND Date <= 9/1/2013

Comment: You have to change the type to datetime. Otherwise your SQL will never work as you need it to. You also need to make sure that the values you pass in can be converted to datetimes. The best format is yyyy-mm-dd hhh:mm:ss

Comment: from what you said I think you mean this query: "SELECT * FROM Ordr Where Date >= 2013-08-08 00:00:00 AND Date <= 2013-09-09 24:00:00" but this gives me an parsing error for the beginning of the first time entry of 00:00:00 I just may not be understanding.

Comment: If you are running the query within the Query editor, you need to wrap the dates in apostrophes: `Where Date >= '2013-08-08'`

Comment: again you are amazing

Answer (score 0):

> I am searching with format MM/DD/YYYY like it is in the table.

This is a common misconception. `date` (and `datetime`) data types do not store formatted dates (dd/mm/yyyy is the *format* you are seeing).

If you're using a string representation of a date (you are here) then you should format it like so:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.NNN
```

This is a universal format and will resolve the issue you are encountering.

An alternative method is to parametrise your queries and pass a date *object*.

Comment: I do not know how to do any of those things. I am very new to programming of any kind. Any code you could but up would be very appreciated.